# GSCRIPT: If statement that if filters are on remove; otherwise continue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find an if statement that checks for filters before running a function. If filters are applied to the worksheet, then undo all filters.

The reason for this is that filters seem to cause problems with macro.

I was able to do this pretty easily in Excel, but I am struggling with it in Gscript.

Thank you

Excel Formula:

```
function FilterOff(){
  If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a script you've tried for this purpose?

Comment: Hi Ross, I included the working Excel formula i've used, but I do not know where to begin with GScript. I can't find a filter class that checks for if a filter is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function removeAllFilters() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var f=shts[i].getFilter();
    if(f) {
      f.remove();
    }
  }
}
```